# spritesheet image used as background fill the container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a selected portion of the background image, taken from spritesheet, fill the whole space in its container.

In this pen, the background image should always fill the character. Also while being resized, which is the main problem.
https://codepen.io/timsim/pen/wdWZWv

If you use background-position, you don't how big the image should be, just where to cut it. Also, setting height and width assumes that it needs to cut that image with dimensions of height and width.

```
#image{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: url(../assets/spritesheet.jpg);
    background-position: -220px -220px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to utilize `background-size` based on the size of your container and the part of the sprite you want to use.

```css
#image {
    width: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.codeandweb.com/blog/2016/05/10/how-to-create-a-sprite-sheet/spritestrip.png);
    background-size: 650%;
    background-position: 21% 146%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id=image></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am having some issues with actually using different images from the first one. How would you pick the second one from the example?

Comment: @sanjihan use `background-position`

Comment: It behaves really strange

Comment: If you set background-position, then the whole resizing breaks

Comment: If you're trying to select the second one, updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  % are the key yes. But selecting image is unintuitive This image above has 6 images. So one would think that you need to specify x percentages 0, 16.66%, 33.33% and so on. but no, you need to go from 0 to 20%, to 40%.. and so on.

Comment: @sanjihan there are 6 images, but there are 5 points that you want to start from on the x-axis. 0 (left edge), 20% (2nd image), 40% (3rd image), etc. So the background position here to select the 2nd image is 21% (close enough to 20%, I used 21 so it would be a little more centered).

Comment: Yes, it appears so. I guess my brain functions differently :D I see no sense in setting 5 points to start images from, if you need 6. What does it even mean to start at 100%..